# Android ConstraintLayout TextView does not wrap in chain_style packed horizontal

Tags: android, word-wrap, android-constraintlayout

I have such constraints that creates chain_style packed between to textviews and if textview has wrap_content defined it doesn't wrap if set to 0dp it occupies all available space so Archived label is always at the right side of the layout not just after first textview

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@{deal.name}"
            tools:text="Deal Name Deal Name Deal Name Deal Name Deal Name Deal Name Deal Name"

            style="@style/ItemDealTitleTextAppearance"
            android:autoSizeTextType="none"


            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"

            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"

            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amountTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/verticalFlow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/archivedTextView"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/archivedTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            style="@style/ArchiveLabelStyle"

            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"

            app:visibleGone="@{deal.isArchived == true}"

            android:text="Archived"

            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/nameTextView"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/nameTextView" />
```

Comment: Share your full layout and what you want to achive.

Comment: If you use `layout_width="0dp"`  you have to specify constraint for start and end, if you use `layout_height="0dp"` you have to specify constraint for top an bottom as `0dp` means `match_constraint`

Comment: it doesn't work if I use wrap content then first long text view does not wrap. If I use 0dp then it wraps but second text view is always pushed to the right edge even it there is just 2 words in first text view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now, there is no chain as the TextView on the right has no end constraint. Add `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` constraint to the `archivedTextView` to create a valid horizontal chain.

Add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to the `nameTextView` and keep its width as `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

This will keep the long text within the constraints and cause it to wrap.

Comment: I've had app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf but doesn't copy-paste it to stackoverflow. But here crucial change was to add app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" to fix this layout.